# UML Class diagram object composed of 4 objects of another class?

Tags: uml

I have one object, call it type A which has four data members of another object type, call it B. How do I show this in a UML class diagram so that its clear there are four B objects type in every A object?

Is the only solution to put "4" next to the arrow head pointing to class B?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achive, in sense of **how you need to distinguish between those objects** in context of their association/link, that is - **what kind of role they play**:

- if there are all equal, no special differences in their role in context of A, them a multiplicity 4..4 will do the job, naming the association end properly (for example my_Bs)
- If these object play different role in connection with A, then you can use separate associations with lower multiplicities each one, 2, 3 or even 4 pieces (for example, if B is a Wheel and A is Car, then you can put 2 associations with multiplicities 2..2 each, and call then "front" and "rear", or even 4 associations "front_left", "front_right"...)

Here is how the both cases look like. On the second one I showd different possible options (with max. 5 elements of B), just to give you an idea.

[image]

It's probably clear by now, but the fundamental concept here is the **role** of the association end.

Comment: Does this mean that I will not be including the data member variable names inside A?

Comment: On the contrary - role names are exactly the data members names, while B + the corresponding multiplicity indicates the type. in my first example you have the data member m_bs: B[4] (see Oliver's answer), while in the second you have 3 data members: first: B, second: Collection(B) and third: Collection (B). The concrete collection depende on the implementation technology (array or so).

Answer (score 0):

Aleks answer is the best. However you can also represent the multiplicity in one box like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cal also use composite structure diagram. See example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, myBs defined as an attribute of type B on class A has a *different meaning* of myBs defined as a association's role between A and B (which is also different as defining it as a composition/aggregation).

If it is an attribute, then it's not a role. In that case, there is only a simple dependency relation between A and B, which must appear in the diagram.

I think that problem comes from unconsciously think from a "Relationnal Data (BMS)" and/or a "Object Oriented Programming" point of view, but UML is not intended for that.
:)